# jQuery code that has been written does not pass correct value based on clicking

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have dynamic list of item from database.
I generate the list using the while loop and echo it inside php.
The problem is the jQuery somehow only recognize the first item eventhough I click on the second item. I want to remove the clicked item directly after the ajax call is success.

this is my PHP code

```
while ($rowresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $rowresult['id'];
    $name = $rowresult['name'];
    $brand= $rowresult['brand'];
    $price = $rowresult['price'];
    $qty = $rowresult['itemQuantity']; 
    $desc = $rowresult['description'];
    $img = $rowresult['itemImage'];

    echo "<div class=\"col-md-12\">";
    echo "<div id=\"cartHeader\" class=\"rowresult cartInfo\">";
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-12\">";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"idValue\" name=\"idValue\" value=\" $id \"/>";
    echo "<span class=\"remove\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"removeAnchor\">&times;</a></span>";
    echo "<p> $brand $name </p>";
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
    echo "<img src=\"$img\" alt=\"Product Image\" width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\"></a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-8\">";
    echo "<span class=\"cartDesc\"> $desc </span> <br>";
    echo "<strong><span class=\"cartDesc\"> RM$price </span></strong>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

and this is my jQuery code

```
$(".removeAnchor").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var itemID = $('#idValue').val();
var self = $(this);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'delete_item.php',
  data: {itemID:itemID},
  success: function(data){
    $("#cartHeader").css({"background" : "red"});
    console.log(itemID);
  }
});
});
```

this is my delete_item.php

```
<?php
$title = "Item Details";

session_start();
include "config.php";

$itemID = $_POST['itemID'];
?>
```

P.S. I am also using bootstrap

Can somebody tell me how come when I click item that is from 1st row onward will still return value that is belong to 1st item?

ANy help given is highly appreciated

Comment: It's set to grab the value of the input `#idValue`?
It's only ever going to return the value of this input field. Are there more than one elements with this ID?

Comment: no sir. only #idValue is used for that textbox. there is no other duplicated  same id

Comment: try to use console.log(data); instead of console.log(itemID); and see what you will get

Comment: sir, the problem is not at retrieving data. The problem occurs right when I click the particular item

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way to fix the problem is:

```
var itemID = $(this).parent().find("#idValue").val();
```

Generally you should try keeping `id` attribute values unique accros much wider scope then just the element's parent.

Comment: sir, now it become undefined

Comment: what $(this).parent() gives ya?

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: go parent().parent().find("#idValue").val(); - you can use dev console in chrome to easily debug it...

Comment: sir, now the jQuery can detect correct itemID, but how can I fadeOut the particular div belong to the clicked item?

Comment: Your div can be reached by:  var fadeoutDiv$  = $(this).parent().parent();